# Calculate time difference in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm new to app building, and wanted to start a simple logbook functionality. For this I need to calculate time differences within a small amount of hours only on daylight hours. On this side I found some coding like beneath, but when I try to put this code inside Xcode12 it will not work. And in playground of my iPad it works fine.

What is going wrong in this code?

```
import SwiftUI


struct About: View {

let time1 = "10:30AM"
let time2 = "1:20PM"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mma 'UTC'"

let date1 = formatter.date(from: time1)!
let date2 = formatter.date(from: time2)!

let elapsedTime = date2.timeIntervalSince(date1)

// convert from seconds to hours, rounding down to the nearest hour
let hours = floor(elapsedTime / 60 / 60)

// we have to subtract the number of seconds in hours from minutes to get
// the remaining minutes, rounding down to the nearest minute (in case you
// want to get seconds down the road)
let minutes = floor((elapsedTime - (hours * 60 * 60)) / 60)

var body: some View {
    Text("\(Int(hours)) hr and \(Int(minutes)) min")        
   }
}

struct About_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    About()
 }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Calendar` guy named `dateComponents(_:from:to:)`.

Comment: @ElTomato What is a "guy"?

Comment: @jnpdx [Instance Method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293176-datecomponents)

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks - I know what an instance method is -- hadn't heard the term "guy" for it before.

Comment: @jnpdx I was wondering the same thing... thankfully the guy cleared it up.